# Yii2 - Remember me does not workk

Tags: yii2, logout, remember-me

I turned on the Remember me field and set the duration to one month

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUserById($userId), $rememberMe == true ? 2629746 : 0);
```

but that doesn't work. The website logs out after an hour of inactivity

Comment: check your config for session duration as well. Enable Auto login if not.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work.
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
 'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'cookieParams' => ['lifetime' => 2628000],
            'timeout' => 2628000, //session expire
        ],